# React - Using Conditional Rendering with window.location.href to change Background image

Tags: reactjs, react-router, conditional-statements

I'm currently trying to create a page where the home page has a background image and the other pages do not. I'm trying to add conditional rendering to accomplish this. My code is below, followed by the App component I want to put it on, but my syntax is clearly wrong (React noobie).

```
if window.location.href == "/" || "/home" ?
    background = url;
else:
    background = none;
```

Here is my app.js (I'm using React-router in the MainNav component):

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);


        render() {
            return (
    <div className="App">

      <div className="contentContainer">
        <div className="navMenu">
          <NavHeader/>
        </div>
        <div className="sideLeftNav">
          <SidebarLeft/>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
          <MainNav/>
        </div>
        <div className="sideRightNav">
          <SidebarRight/>
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <Footer/>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I think I've made this more difficult on myself then it needs to be, but I'm very new to props and state and I can't figure it out from reading other problems. I simply want to display the background image on my initial state ("/") and {home} component, with no background image on the other components. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's few ways you could achieve this output. But using `window.location.href` is not nice since you're using `react-router`. (Here `window.location.href` is a browser variable where output will be complete url such as `http://ab.com/12/cd` and will have to parse to get actual application route.) 

Instead use `this.props.location` property of `react-router`. Check current route and set background if need-be in either `constructor` or `render` function.

```
render(){
   const { location } = this.props
   const imgSrc = null

   if(location.pathname == "/" || location.pathname == "/home"){
      imgSrc = "ab.com/cd.jpg"
   }

   return (
      { imgSrc && <div ..... > </div>}
   )
}
```

However this is in accordance with suggested code given. Another possible approach is placing background image within those relevant component without checking for url or route. As an example somewhere, there should be instance of `<Router>` from `react-router`

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/" component={BasicComponent}
  <Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent}
  <Route path="/other" component={OtherComponent}
</Router>
```

Here in `BasicComponent` and `HomeComponent` you could include background image in `render` function. This is also a viable approach.

Comment: The first approach may apparently not work if the router is inside `<MainNav/>` and OP wants to change background of, for example, `<div className="App">`. The parent component has no reason to re-render unless `MainNav` has a prop callback to call whenever the background should be changed.

Comment: If that's the case, will have to use callback to pass on `imgSrc` back to `<App />` parent component from `<MainNav />`. Else can use proposed `window.location.href` and `if` condition in `<App />` component and pass on `imgSrc` to `<MainNav />`. There wouldn't any work around it since access to `react-router` is not possible as well as we're not using some state management such as `redux` or `mobx`.

Comment: Hey guys, does it look like I will have to use Redux for the state management to complete the desired outcome? I can find a few courses to start learning. I have been beating my head against the wall just trying to find the right direction. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Hi @Dilby, if you're just using few components as of now, and if these components are mostly *presentational components*, then there isn't much need for `redux` or such state management library. However you'll have to communicate between components using `props` and `callback functions`, where you'll have to keep track of data flow. (PS: mark this as answer if you found this acceptable.)