# React way of hiding component does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How to hide components in reactjs when

```
{ window.location.pathname !== "/" && <contact /> }
```

don't work, the problem is that im trying to hide the  component from my landing page but show on all other subpages, but the problem is when i use that code the component disappear from all pages, except the weird thing is that when i refresh the page with cmd+R the component on the subpages appears

and also here is my App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';



//includes css
import './assets/css/style.min.css';
import './assets/css/header.min.css';
import './assets/css/kontakt.min.css';
import './assets/css/Kontaktformular.min.css';
import './assets/css/agatoveihriska.min.css';

//includes css-responzive
import './assets/css/style-responsive.min.css';
import './assets/css/style-responsive.min.css';

//components
import mail from './sendemail.php';
import Homepage from './components/pages/homePage';
import Kontakt from './components/pages/kontakt';
import Header from './components/headerComponent/header';
import Agatoveihriska from './components/pages/agatoveihriska.js';
import Kontaktformular from './components/repeating/kontaktformular.js';




class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

  componentDidMount() {
        this._div.scrollTop = 0
    }



  render() {

const Home = () => <p>Home</p>;

    return (

      <Router>
        <div className="App" ref={(ref) => this._div = ref}>


            <Header  />

            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route  path='/Kontakt' component={Kontakt} />
            <Route  path='/Kontaktformular' component={Kontaktformular} />
            <Route  path='/Agatoveihriska' component={Agatoveihriska} />



            { window.location.pathname !== "/" && <Kontaktformular /> }



        </div>
      </Router>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is that the actual class? I'm not seeing an `import Kontaktformular` anywhere. You also need to prepare for mods closing this as duplicate of your previous question.

Comment: the import has lost in the copy paste process, yes ibut nobody can solve my question...

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49140953/react-using-conditional-rendering-with-window-location-href-to-change-backgrou

Comment: @SebastiánDanáč Just to make sure, did you see my live example? https://codesandbox.io/s/2wj1658j6n It works just fine, does need a refresh but also isn't broken by one, exactly like it's supposed to be.

Comment: the problem was in my react syntax, i had route and router in one component (app.js) after i put router to my index.js like <router><app.js/></router>  and removed router from app.js it worked just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

render() {
  return(
    this.props.location.pathname !== "/" && <Kontaktformular />
  )
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: ./src/App.js
Syntax error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (155:6)

  153 |       this.props.location.pathname !== "/" && <Kontaktformular />
  154 | 
> 155 |       <Router>
      |       ^
  156 |         <div className="App" ref={(ref) => this._div = ref}>
  157 | 
  158 |  - this error appears

Comment: Sorry I didn't pay attention to syntax. The idea is not to use `window` object, because React won't react to its changes. You must find a way how to implement `location` property of `react-router`.

Comment: im trying to find the way 3 days now... :D

Comment: I see the problem in your application structure. Maybe in your `App.js` instead of all routes you can have only `Router` and the main `Route` '/' without `exact` ... leading to a container kind of `Layout.js` and there you are inside the router and you can connect it and use its properties.

Comment: Anyway Im Czech so we can speak in our languages :D

Comment: can you provide some working example to it ? anyway i found out that when i refresh the site the component dissapear or appear exactly like it should so if you cloud provide some js code that wloud refresh the component every time there is a route change we cloud solve that, and im fine with english because maybe somebody else will read it and it cloud help him :)

Comment: maybe write some js code that would refresh kontaktformular component every time when there is a route change